# Anyone do step-by-step PHP debugging on a Mac with Textmate & local test server (Not MAMP/XAMPP)?

Tags: php, debugging

**What do you all use?**

I'm getting sick of vardumping everything, I just wrote this massive function that isn't quite working correctly. I would love to be able to step-through the php code. I heard macgdbp was pretty good, but it seems like its iffy unless you use MAMP.

This is for mac users who develop with Textmate and took the time to install & compile PHP/MySQL without the assistance of a web server package. What do you use to debug PHP? I was checking out FirePHP but I don't think it has step-by-step debugging of PHP.

THanks! 
Matt Mueller

Answer (score 1):

[Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote) and [MacGDBp](http://www.bluestatic.org/software/macgdbp/index.php) should do the trick

(Disclaimer: I've used Xdebug and like it, but I've never used that particular client)

Comment: Second this, Xdebug works flawlessly with Netbeans on Mac OSX 10.4/5/6.